# Modules are installed but imports still throw errors (pandas)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, module

I am having trouble importing modules in python 2.7.13. I run the python script and this is the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

This is the case for any other modules that I need to `import`, not just `pandas`.

**pip list:**

```
numexpr (2.2.2)
numpy (1.8.2)
oauth (1.0.1)
openpyxl (1.7.0)
PAM (0.4.2)
pandas (0.13.1)
python-apt (0.9.3.5ubuntu2)
python-dateutil (1.5)
python-debian (0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2)
pytz (2012rc0)
PyYAML (3.10)
requestbuilder (0.1.0b1)
requests (2.2.1)
scipy (0.13.3)
xlrd (0.9.2)
xlwt (0.7.5)
```

**python -V:**

```
Python 2.7.13
```

**pip -V:**

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

This problem happened because I just had upgraded my python from 2.7.6 to 2.7.13. I will only be working with 2.7.13, so no need to set up virtualenv for different python versions.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling `pandas`?

Comment: how did you install the libraries? is python in the PATH variable ?

Comment: Yes, I have. I remove it and reinstalled it. And to install Python 2.7.13 I downloaded the `.tgz` extracted ran `./configure` and `sudo make install` than restarted the server. And this is my `echo $PATH`: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`.

Comment: I have added python to my PATH using: `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/python"` but still error.

Comment: try this in the terminal: `sudo -H python -m pip install pandas`

Comment: Ashkan, that command outputs: `/usr/local/bin/python: no module named pip`

Comment: That is strange since Python 2.7.9 and later comes with pip. Can you see if you have pip in `/usr/local/bin`? If not, install it by typing `sudo apt-get install python-pip` in the terminal. I think the pip you are using to install packages is for a different python you have on your system.

Comment: I looked into `usr/local/bin` and I do see pip in there. I also see `pip2`,`pip2.7`. I tried `pip2.7 install pandas` and pip2, but it says `Requirement already satisfied`.

Comment: In Python 2.7.13, `pip` is an executable, not a Python script (even though it's still in the `/Python/Scripts` directory, so I wouldn't expect `sudo -H python -m pip install pandas` to work.

Comment: So what do you recommend I do, martineau?